# jquery.columns.js で表示した検索ボックスに自作のサジェスト機能を組み合わせたい

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

いつもお世話になっております。

[jquery.columns.min.js](http://michaeleisenbraun.com/columns/)
上記JSファイルに自分で作成してあるサジェスト機能を組み込みたいのです。
下記のJSファイル、HTMLが自分で作成したサジェスト機能です。
googleサジェスト機能を思い浮かんでいただければイメージしやすいと思います。

入力要素を参照する機能をご存知の方アドバイス頂けないでしょうか？
[公式サイト](http://michaeleisenbraun.com/columns/)

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
//ac2にサジェスト候補がはいる
$("#ac2").autocomplete({
 source: function(req, resp){
  $.ajax({
　　　　　　　　　//ここからサジェスト候補をとってくる
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8180/api/stock/keyword",
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
      car_name : req.term
      },
            //手入力した際にURL先に候補がある場合の処理
      success: function(o){
       resp(o);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ts, err){
       resp(['']);
      }
    });

 }
});
});
```

```html
　　<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DataTable</title>
<link id="style" href="css/classic.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/table.js"></script>
<script src="js/suggest.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.columns.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="columns"></div>
<input type="text"  id="ac2"  name="car_name" >
<input type="submit" value="検索"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$().autocomplete()` の詳細が書かれていませんが、自作のライブラリなのでしょうか？また、あなたの試した組み込み方で何故上手くいかないのかは、その組み込んだ後のコード（columnsやautocompleteを呼び出す側）を提示されないとわかりませんが、そこはもう掘り下げなくてよいのでしょうか？

Comment: unaristさん
自作のライブラリです。
ただJSONデータからサジェスト候補として呼び出す単純なライブラリです。

そうですね。もう少し詳しく書きます。
忠告ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

jquery.columns.js は指定した要素の中にテーブルや検索ボックスを同期的に生成します。そのため、 `$(..).columns()` を実行した後であれば、検索ボックスの要素を取得してイベントを設定したり等行えるはずです。

例えば以下のコードでは、検索ボックスに入力した文字数に比例してテーブルが下に移動します。

```js
/*** 
 * Copyright (c) 2014 
 * Licensed under the MIT License.
 *
 * Author: Michael Eisenbraun
 * Version: 2.2.2
 * Requires: jQuery 1.7.2+
 * Documentation: http://eisenbraun.github.io/columns/
 */if(!window.console)var console={log:function(){}};(function(e){e.fn.columns=function(n){var r=[],i=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);typeof n=="string"?this.each(function(){var t=e.data(this,"columns");if(typeof t=="undefined"||!e.isFunction(t[n]))return e.error('No such method "'+n+'" for Columns');var s=t[n].apply(t,i);s!==undefined&&s!==t&&r.push(s)}):this.each(function(){e.data(this,"columns")||e.data(this,"columns",new t(this,n))});return r.length===0?this.data("columns"):r.length===1?r[0]:r};var t=function(t,n){this.$el=e(t);n&&e.extend(this,n);this.VERSION="2.2.2";this.sort=function(){function n(e,n,r){n=n?-1:1;return function(i,s){i=i[e];s=s[e];if(t.test(i)&&t.test(s)){i=new Date(i);i=Date.parse(i);s=new Date(s);s=Date.parse(s)}else if(typeof r!="undefined"){i=r(i);s=r(s)}return i<s?n*-1:i>s?n*1:0}}var e=this,t=/^(Jan|January|Feb|February|Mar|March|Apr|April|May|Jun|June|Jul|July|Aug|August|Sep|September|Oct|October|Nov|November|Dec|December|(0?\d{1})|(10|11|12))(-|\s|\/|\.)(0?[1-9]|(1|2)[0-9]|3(0|1))(-|\s|\/|\.|,\s)(19|20)?\d\d$/i;e.total&&e.sortBy&&typeof e.data[0][e.sortBy]!="undefined"&&e.data.sort(n(e.sortBy,e.reverse))};this.filter=function(){var t=this,n=t.searchableFields.length;if(t.query){var r=new RegExp(t.query,"gi");t.data=e.grep(t.data,function(e){for(var i=0;i<n;i++)if(typeof e[t.searchableFields[i]]=="string"){if(e[t.searchableFields[i]].match(r))return!0}else if(typeof e[t.searchableFields[i]]=="number"&&e[t.searchableFields[i]]==t.query)return!0;return!1})}t.total=t.data.length};this.paginate=function(){var e=this;e.pages=Math.ceil(e.data.length/e.size);e.page=e.page<=e.pages?e.page:1;e.setRange();e.data=e.data.slice(e.range.start-1,e.range.end)};this.condition=function(){var e=this,t=[];if(e.schema){var n=e.data.length,r=e.schema.length;for(var i=0;i<n;i++){var s=e.data[i],o={};for(var u=0;u<r;u++){var a=e.schema[u];if(a.condition&&!a.condition(s[a.key])){o=null;break}o[a.key]=s[a.key]}o&&t.push(o)}e.data=t}};this.chevron=function(e,t){return Mustache.render(e,t)};this.create=function(){function n(){t.thead=[];e.each(t.schema,function(n,r){if(!r.hide){var i={};e.inArray(r.key,t.sortableFields)===-1?i.notSortable=!0:t.sortBy===r.key?t.reverse?i.sortedDown=!0:i.sortedUp=!0:i.sortable=!0;i.key=r.key;i.header=r.header;t.thead.push(i)}})}function r(n,r){var i=[];n%2===0?i.push('<tr data-columns-row-id="'+n+'" class="'+t.evenRowClass+'">'):i.push('<tr data-columns-row-id="'+n+'" class="'+t.oddRowClass+'">');e.each(t.schema,function(e,n){n.hide||(n.template?i.push("<td>"+t.chevron(n.template,r)+"</td>"):i.push("<td>"+r[n.key]+"</td>"))});i.push("</tr>");return i}function i(){var n=[];n.push("<select>");e.each(t.showRows,function(e,r){var i='<option value="'+r+'"';r===t.size&&(i+='selected="selected"');i+=">"+r+"</option>";n.push(i)});n.push("</select>");t.showRowsMenu=n.join("")}function s(){t.rows=[];t.total?e.each(t.data,function(e,i){e===0&&n();t.rows.push(r(e,i).join(""))}):t.rows.push('<tr class="'+t.evenRowClass+'"><td colspan="'+t.schema.length+'"><em>No Results</em></td>')}var t=this;t.resetData();t.searching&&t.filter();t.sorting&&t.sort();t.paginating&&t.paginate();s();i();var o={prevPage:t.page-1,nextPage:t.page+1,prevPageExists:t.pageExists(t.page-1),nextPageExists:t.pageExists(t.page+1),resultRange:t.range,tableTotal:t.total,showRowsMenu:t.showRowsMenu,rows:t.rows,headers:t.thead,query:t.query,search:t.search,table:t.table};e.extend(t.view,o);t.plugins&&e.each(t.plugins,function(e,n){typeof ColumnsPlugins!="undefined"&&typeof ColumnsPlugins[n]!="undefined"&&ColumnsPlugins[n].create.call(t)});if(t.search){t.$el.html(t.chevron(t.template,t.view));t.search=!1}else{e("[data-columns-table]",t.$el).remove();t.$el.append(t.chevron(t.template,t.view))}return!0};this.init=function(){function n(){t.schema=[];e.each(t.data[0],function(e){t.schema.push({header:e,key:e})})}function r(){t.searchableFields=[];e.each(t.data[0],function(e){t.searchableFields.push(e)})}function i(){t.sortableFields=[];e.each(t.data[0],function(e){t.sortableFields.push(e)})}function s(){e.ajax({url:t.templateFile,async:!1,success:function(e){t.template=e},error:function(){e.error("Template could not be found.")}})}var t=this;if(e.isArray(t.data)){t.master=[];t.view={};t.$el.addClass("columns");t.$el.on("click",".ui-table-sortable",function(n){var r=e(this).data("columns-sortby");t.sortBy===r&&(t.reverse=t.reverse?!1:!0);t.sortBy=r;t.sortHandler(n)});t.$el.on("click",".ui-table-control-next, .ui-table-control-prev",function(n){t.page=e(this).data("columns-page");t.pageHandler(n)});t.$el.on("keyup",".ui-table-search",function(n){t.query=e(this).val();t.searchHandler(n)});t.$el.on("change",".ui-table-size select",function(n){t.size=parseInt(e(this).val());t.sizeHandler(n)});t.plugins&&e.each(t.plugins,function(e,n){typeof ColumnsPlugins!="undefined"&&typeof ColumnsPlugins[n]!="undefined"&&ColumnsPlugins[n].init.call(t)});t.conditioning&&t.condition();t.schema||n();t.searchableFields||r();t.sortableFields||i();t.templateFile&&s();e.extend(t.master,t.data);t.create()}else e.error('The "data" parameter must be an array.')};this.init()};t.prototype={evenRowClass:"ui-table-rows-even",oddRowClass:"ui-table-rows-odd",liveSearch:!0,page:1,pages:1,plugins:null,query:null,reverse:!1,pagination:!0,schema:null,search:!0,searchableFields:null,showRows:[5,10,25,50],size:5,sortableFields:null,sortBy:null,table:!0,templateFile:null,template:'<!-- Search Box: Only rendered while search is true --> {{#search}} <div class="ui-columns-search"> <input class="ui-table-search" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="query" data-columns-search="true" value="{{query}}" /> </div> {{/search}} <!-- Search Box: Only rendered while search is true --> <!-- Columns Table: Only rendered while table is true --> {{#table}} <div class="ui-columns-table" data-columns-table="true"> <table class="ui-table"> <!-- Columns Table Head: Headers have 4 possible states (sortable, notSortable, sortedUp, sortedDown) --> <thead> {{#headers}} {{#sortable}} <th class="ui-table-sortable" data-columns-sortby="{{key}}">{{header}}</th> {{/sortable}} {{#notSortable}} <th class="">{{header}}</th> {{/notSortable}} {{#sortedUp}} <th class="ui-table-sort-up ui-table-sortable" data-columns-sortby="{{key}}">{{header}} <span class="ui-arrow">&#x25B2;</span></th> {{/sortedUp}} {{#sortedDown}} <th class="ui-table-sort-down ui-table-sortable" data-columns-sortby="{{key}}">{{header}} <span class="ui-arrow">&#x25BC;</span></th> {{/sortedDown}} {{/headers}} </thead> <!-- Columns Table Head: Headers have 4 possible states (sortable, notSortable, sortedUp, sortedDown) --> <!-- Columns Table Body: Table columns are rendered outside of this template  --> <tbody> {{#rows}} {{{.}}} {{/rows}} </tbody> <!-- Columns Table Body: Table columns are rendered outside of this template  --> </table> <!-- Columns Controls  --> <div class="ui-table-footer"> <span class="ui-table-size">Show rows: {{{showRowsMenu}}}</span> <span class="ui-table-results">Results: <strong>{{resultRange.start}} &ndash; {{resultRange.end}}</strong> of <strong>{{tableTotal}}</strong> </span> <span class="ui-table-controls"> {{#prevPageExists}} <span class="ui-table-control-prev" data-columns-page="{{prevPage}}"> <img src="images/arrow-left.png"> </span> {{/prevPageExists}} {{^prevPageExists}} <span class="ui-table-control-disabled"> <img src="images/arrow-left.png"> </span> {{/prevPageExists}} {{#nextPageExists}} <span class="ui-table-control-next" data-columns-page="{{nextPage}}"> <img src="images/arrow-right.png"> </span> {{/nextPageExists}} {{^nextPageExists}} <span class="ui-table-control-disabled"> <img src="images/arrow-right.png"> </span> {{/nextPageExists}} </span> </div> <!-- Columns Controls  --> </div> {{/table}} <!-- Columns Table: Only rendered while table is true -->',conditioning:!0,paginating:!0,searching:!0,sorting:!0,pageHandler:function(){this.create()},searchHandler:function(e){this.liveSearch?this.create():e.keyCode=="13"&&this.create()},sizeHandler:function(){this.create()},sortHandler:function(){this.page=1;this.create()},destroy:function(){this.$el.data("columns",null);this.$el.empty();return!0},getObject:function(){return this},getPage:function(){return this.page},getQuery:function(){return this.query},getRange:function(){return this.range},getRows:function(){return this.rows},getShowRowsMenu:function(){return this.showRowsMenu},getTemplate:function(){return this.template},getThead:function(){return this.thead},getTotal:function(){return this.total},getVersion:function(){return this.VERSION},getView:function(){return this.view},gotoPage:function(e){if(this.pageExists(e)){this.page=e;this.create();return!0}return!1},pageExists:function(e){return e>0&&e<=this.pages?!0:!1},resetData:function(e){this.data=this.master.slice(0);return this.data},setMaster:function(t){if(e.isArray(t)){this.master=t;return!0}return!1},setPage:function(e){this.page=this.pageExists(e)?e:this.page;return this.page},setRange:function(){var e=(this.page-1)*this.size,t=e+this.size<this.total?e+this.size:this.total;this.range={start:e+1,end:t}},setTotal:function(e){this.total=e;return!0},startTime:null,endTime:null,startTimer:function(){var e=new Date;this.startTime=e.getTime()},endTimer:function(){var e=new Date;this.endTime=e.getTime()},getTimer:function(){console.log((this.endTime-this.startTime)/1e3)}}})(jQuery);(function(e,t){e.Mustache=t({})})(this,function(e){function r(e){return typeof e=="function"}function i(e){return e.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g,"\\$&")}function o(e,t){return s.call(e,t)}function a(e){return!o(u,e)}function l(e){return String(e).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g,function(e){return f[e]})}function m(t,r){function m(){if(f&&!l)while(u.length)delete o[u.pop()];else u=[];f=!1;l=!1}function x(e){typeof e=="string"&&(e=e.split(h,2));if(!n(e)||e.length!==2)throw new Error("Invalid tags: "+e);w=new RegExp(i(e[0])+"\\s*");E=new RegExp("\\s*"+i(e[1]));S=new RegExp("\\s*"+i("}"+e[1]))}if(!t)return[];var s=[],o=[],u=[],f=!1,l=!1,w,E,S;x(r||e.tags);var T=new b(t),N,C,k,L,A,O;while(!T.eos()){N=T.pos;k=T.scanUntil(w);if(k)for(var M=0,_=k.length;M<_;++M){L=k.charAt(M);a(L)?u.push(o.length):l=!0;o.push(["text",L,N,N+1]);N+=1;L==="\n"&&m()}if(!T.scan(w))break;f=!0;C=T.scan(v)||"name";T.scan(c);if(C==="="){k=T.scanUntil(p);T.scan(p);T.scanUntil(E)}else if(C==="{"){k=T.scanUntil(S);T.scan(d);T.scanUntil(E);C="&"}else k=T.scanUntil(E);if(!T.scan(E))throw new Error("Unclosed tag at "+T.pos);A=[C,k,N,T.pos];o.push(A);if(C==="#"||C==="^")s.push(A);else if(C==="/"){O=s.pop();if(!O)throw new Error('Unopened section "'+k+'" at '+N);if(O[1]!==k)throw new Error('Unclosed section "'+O[1]+'" at '+N)}else C==="name"||C==="{"||C==="&"?l=!0:C==="="&&x(k)}O=s.pop();if(O)throw new Error('Unclosed section "'+O[1]+'" at '+T.pos);return y(g(o))}function g(e){var t=[],n,r;for(var i=0,s=e.length;i<s;++i){n=e[i];if(n)if(n[0]==="text"&&r&&r[0]==="text"){r[1]+=n[1];r[3]=n[3]}else{t.push(n);r=n}}return t}function y(e){var t=[],n=t,r=[],i,s;for(var o=0,u=e.length;o<u;++o){i=e[o];switch(i[0]){case"#":case"^":n.push(i);r.push(i);n=i[4]=[];break;case"/":s=r.pop();s[5]=i[2];n=r.length>0?r[r.length-1][4]:t;break;default:n.push(i)}}return t}function b(e){this.string=e;this.tail=e;this.pos=0}function w(e,t){this.view=e==null?{}:e;this.cache={".":this.view};this.parent=t}function E(){this.cache={}}var t=Object.prototype.toString,n=Array.isArray||function(e){return t.call(e)==="[object Array]"},s=RegExp.prototype.test,u=/\S/,f={"&":"&amp;","<":"&lt;",">":"&gt;",'"':"&quot;","'":"&#39;","/":"&#x2F;"},c=/\s*/,h=/\s+/,p=/\s*=/,d=/\s*\}/,v=/#|\^|\/|>|\{|&|=|!/;b.prototype.eos=function(){return this.tail===""};b.prototype.scan=function(e){var t=this.tail.match(e);if(!t||t.index!==0)return"";var n=t[0];this.tail=this.tail.substring(n.length);this.pos+=n.length;return n};b.prototype.scanUntil=function(e){var t=this.tail.search(e),n;switch(t){case-1:n=this.tail;this.tail="";break;case 0:n="";break;default:n=this.tail.substring(0,t);this.tail=this.tail.substring(t)}this.pos+=n.length;return n};w.prototype.push=function(e){return new w(e,this)};w.prototype.lookup=function(e){var t=this.cache,n;if(e in t)n=t[e];else{var i=this,s,o;while(i){if(e.indexOf(".")>0){n=i.view;s=e.split(".");o=0;while(n!=null&&o<s.length)n=n[s[o++]]}else n=i.view[e];if(n!=null)break;i=i.parent}t[e]=n}r(n)&&(n=n.call(this.view));return n};E.prototype.clearCache=function(){this.cache={}};E.prototype.parse=function(e,t){var n=this.cache,r=n[e];r==null&&(r=n[e]=m(e,t));return r};E.prototype.render=function(e,t,n){var r=this.parse(e),i=t instanceof w?t:new w(t);return this.renderTokens(r,i,n,e)};E.prototype.renderTokens=function(t,i,s,o){function f(e){return a.render(e,i,s)}var u="",a=this,l,c;for(var h=0,p=t.length;h<p;++h){l=t[h];switch(l[0]){case"#":c=i.lookup(l[1]);if(!c)continue;if(n(c))for(var d=0,v=c.length;d<v;++d)u+=this.renderTokens(l[4],i.push(c[d]),s,o);else if(typeof c=="object"||typeof c=="string")u+=this.renderTokens(l[4],i.push(c),s,o);else if(r(c)){if(typeof o!="string")throw new Error("Cannot use higher-order sections without the original template");c=c.call(i.view,o.slice(l[3],l[5]),f);c!=null&&(u+=c)}else u+=this.renderTokens(l[4],i,s,o);break;case"^":c=i.lookup(l[1]);if(!c||n(c)&&c.length===0)u+=this.renderTokens(l[4],i,s,o);break;case">":if(!s)continue;c=r(s)?s(l[1]):s[l[1]];c!=null&&(u+=this.renderTokens(this.parse(c),i,s,c));break;case"&":c=i.lookup(l[1]);c!=null&&(u+=c);break;case"name":c=i.lookup(l[1]);c!=null&&(u+=e.escape(c));break;case"text":u+=l[1]}}return u};e.name="mustache.js";e.version="0.8.1";e.tags=["{{","}}"];var S=new E;e.clearCache=function(){return S.clearCache()};e.parse=function(e,t){return S.parse(e,t)};e.render=function(e,t,n){return S.render(e,t,n)};e.to_html=function(t,n,i,s){var o=e.render(t,n,i);if(!r(s))return o;s(o)};e.escape=l;e.Scanner=b;e.Context=w;e.Writer=E;return e});
     
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var json = [{"col1":"row1", "col2":"row1", "col3":"row1"}, {"col1":"row2", "col2":"row2", "col3":"row2"}]; 
    $('#columns').columns({
      data: json
    });
    // $('#columns .ui-table-search').autocomplete(...)
    $('#columns .ui-table-search').on('keyup', function(){
      $(this).css('margin-bottom', $(this).val().length * 10);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="columns"></div>
```

ここでは検索ボックスに対して `.on()` を使っていますが、これをあなたの `.autocomplete()` に置き換えれば動作するのでは、と思うのですが如何でしょうか。

---

すみません、単純に「on」を「autocomplete」に置き換えるということではなく、あなたが質問に書いていたような autocomplete の適切な呼び出しをここで行ってほしい、という意味合いでした。`<input type="text" id="ac2">`は使わないため、`$("#ac2")` に対する呼び出しは行いません。

jquery.columns.js をどのように呼び出しているのかわかりませんが、恐らく以下のような全体像になるのではないでしょうか。

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // TODO: ここにあなたの求める jquery.columns.jsの呼び出しを書いてください
  $('xxx').columns({
    ...
  });

  // columnsが生成した検索ボックスに対して
  // あなたの実装したautocompleteを呼び出します
  $("#columns .ui-table-search").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp){
      $.ajax({
　　　  //ここからサジェスト候補をとってくる
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8180/api/stock/keyword",
        //以下略
      });
    }
  });
});
```

重要なのは、jquery.columns.js の処理の後に、`.autocomplete()` を実行するということです。

ちなみに、自分で配置した `<input type="text" id="ac2">` の代わりに jquery.columns.js で生成される検索ボックスに `$().autocomplete()` を適用したい、という話だと考えていますが、もしこれが違うのであれば、この回答は全く見当違いということになります。

Comment: unarist様
何度か試したんですができないです。。。
unarist様のサンプルコードでテキストボックスに影響を与えることはできたのですが、自分の作成したJSと記述が異なるためかと思いますがどうでしょうか？
ある程度JSを訂正しないといけないのでしょうか？

Comment: @たかぽん お使いのautocompleteがjQueryオブジェクトの指す要素以外の要素に依存していたり、特定の構造に依存している場合は動かないかもしれません。また、columnsのCSSと競合して正しく表示されないかもしれません。いずれにせよ、autocompleteの実装や、どのように「記述が異なる」のかが示されないのであれば、具体的なアドバイスをするのは難しいです。

Comment: unarist様
ご返答ありがとうございます。記述はまず指摘された通りだとこのような記述に変更しました。
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#ac2").autocomplete({
     source: function(req, resp){
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8180/api/stockcars/keyword",
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
      car_name : req.term
      },
      success: function(o){
       resp(o);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ts, err){
       resp(['']);
    });
    $('#columns .ui-table-search').autocomplete('keyup', function(){
    });
  });
記述が異なるというのは 中身の内容が違うという意味です。

Comment: @たかぽん 回答に追記しましたので、ご確認ください。

Comment: unarist様
ご親切にありがとうございます。
呼び出し方は 　HTMLに<div id="columns"></div>　でcolumnsを呼び出しを行っています。
なのでこの記述だと呼び出せないかもしれないです。エラーが出ているので。。

Comment: 続きです。
 >$("#columns .ui-table-search").autocomplete({
のautocompleteだとnot a functionとでるのでunarist様の.onだとエラーが消えます。なので.onにするべきなんですかね・・・？

Comment: @たかぽん `<div id="columns">` だけではcolumnsは実行されないと思います。例えば公式サイトのサンプルでは `$("#columns").columns()` で `<div id="columns">` にcolumnsを適用しています。 / not a function と出てしまうなら、やはりHTML全体やautocompleteの実装を見ないとこれ以上のアドバイスのしようがありません。

Comment: unarist様

恐れ入ります。試してみます。
質問編集し、HTML全体を書き足しました。あまりいい情報はないかと思いますが。。。サジェストの実装部分をお見せすることは出来ないので文章で説明すると入力ボックスに適切な文字を入れるとただサジェスト候補がでるだけでございます。

Comment: @たかぽん 外見上の挙動を説明されても、問題はどういう実装になっているかですから・・・申し訳ないですがお手上げです。

Comment: unarist様
色々と親身に答えてただいてありがとうございました。
力不足で悔しいです。

Answer (score 0):

ドキュメントが公開されているサイトには特に注記されていませんでしたが、サンプルコードのソースを見てみると、絞り込み条件を入力するテキストボックスである`<input>`要素のclass属性に ui-table-search を追加すると、columnで出力している内容の絞りこみが自動的に行われているようです。

公開サイトのExample1～5で動作検証をしてみたところ、ui-table-searchの名前を変えることで動作しませんでした。

またこれらのサンプルでは、columnsで出力している表の要素`<div id="example1" class="columns">`の子要素に、`<input class="ui-table-searc">`となっておりましたので、これらが動作するための暗黙ルールになっているかもしれません（検証しておりません、あしからず）

参考になれば幸いです。